# jsp unable to compile class for jsp

Tags: jsp

message: Unable to compile class for JSP:

description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 32 in the generated java file The method
>   getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type
>   JspFactory
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

i am having 28 jsp files i dont know where this error is occuring and what is the problem

i am using odbc14.jar,jsp-api.jar,servelet-api.jar

Answer (score 0):

It could be becuase you have other jars in you're WEB-INF/lib, if you have this jars **javax.servlet.jsp.jar** or
**javax.servlet.jar** delete them.

You could also check that you're are using at least the 2.5 version of the Servlet Specification you can check it in the version attribute of your web.xml, and check if your container supports it version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the below configuration,

Step1:

> check you java verion.If the java verion is 8 and apache version 7
>   means it throwing that kind of error.
>
> So make sure that java and apache verion. Because some times apache not support higher version of that

Step2:

> Add the this line to all jsp page